# How to call a Controller in a View but stay in the same View without reloading?

Tags: php, laravel

View: **test.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <form action="{{route('test')}}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <input type="text" id="text" name="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Routes: **web.php**

```
Route::post('/test',[App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'test'])->name('test');
```

Controllers: **TestController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How can I submit that form without reloading the view or redirecting it to the same view. It needs to use a Controller but maybe doing something with AJAX? Or Laravel provides a way to do so?

Comment: AJAX is the way to go.

Comment: How would you do it? Any link to give an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AJAX you can do something like:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
     
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      URL: "{{route('test')}}",
      data: data,
      success: function () {
        // Display message back to the user here
      }
    });
 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```